# Typescript throwing an error on valueAsDate

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following Javascript code:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 7);
document.getElementById('txtCreateGroupExpirationDate').valueAsDate = now;
```

When I throw this code into a TypeScript file, TypeScript complains with the following error:

> Property 'valueAsDate' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

My Javascript works fine and `valueAsDate` is a legal property, as defined by the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). In addition, you can see that this property is defined in the [Microsoft Typescript Core](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts).

So why am I getting this error? I am using Typescript 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`valueAsDate` is only supported on `HTMLInputElement`, and TypeScript doesn't know what kind of element `txtCreateGroupExpirationDate` is. Use a type assertion to change the type of the expression:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('txtCreateGroupExpirationDate')).valueAsDate = now;
```

Comment: That made perfect sense. Thank you!